# ASP.NET Core: values not passed to action method correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core application, and I am encountering an issue where the values from a form in a Razor view are not being passed correctly to an action method. Specifically, I have a `HttpPost` action method that should receive values for `salleId` and `equipmentName`, but they consistently arrive as 0 and null, respectively.

Razor view (`Create.cshtml`):

```
<div>
    <h2>Create Equipement</h2>
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SalleId"></label>
            <input asp-for="SalleId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="SalleId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EquipmentName"></label>
            <input asp-for="EquipmentName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EquipmentName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

`EquipmentViewModel` class:

```
namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class EquipmentViewModel
    {
        public int SalleId { get; set; }
        public string? EquipmentName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`HttpPost` action method in `EquipementController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(int salleId, string equipmentName)
{
    // Check if the SalleId exists in the Salles table
    var salle = _context.Salles.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CodeSalle == salleId);

    if (salle != null)
    {
        // SalleId is valid, create the Equipement
        var equipement = new Equipement
        {
            SalleId = salle.CodeSalle, // Use the valid SalleId
            EquipmentName = equipmentName
        };

        _context.Equipements.Add(equipement);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // Redirect to a success page or display a success message
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        // SalleId is invalid, handle the error (e.g., show an error message)
        // You might want to add some error handling logic here
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Routing configuration (in `Startup.cs`):

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "createEquipement",
    pattern: "Equipement/Create/{id?}", // Define the URL pattern for the Create action
    defaults: new { controller = "Equipement", action = "Create" } // Specify the controller and action
);
```

Issue summary: despite all these checks and validations, the values for `salleId` and `equipmentName` in the `HttpPost` action method are consistently arriving as 0 and null, respectively. I am seeking guidance on identifying and resolving this issue.

Any help or insights on what could be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried your code and it works correctly , Post method can receive value successfully. Have you checked the payload in http request via developer tools?

Comment: @XinranShen   +  this {WebApplication4.Controllers.EquipementController} WebApplication4.Controllers.EquipementController
  salleId null int?
  equipmentName null string
the payload is empty : Request URL:
https://localhost:44328/Equipement/create
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200
Remote Address:
[::1]:44328
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Encoding:
gzip
Server:
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary:
:authority:
localhost:44328
:method:
POST
:path:
/Equipement/create

Content-Length:
0
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1

Comment: I fixed the problem by recreating a new project. Thank you for informing me that the code works